# have a border before but not after thumb in an input slider

Tags: reactjs, input, slider

[image]

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: centre stretch;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  border: solid 1px #9B9A9A;
  margin-left: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" class="slider" />
</div>
```

Is it possible that the border be present only after the thumb of the slider and not before it. It is possible to use 2 things in class name like below but what should be written instead of beforeSlider, any way to check x,y value or pixel something?:

```
<div className="slidecontainer">
  <input
    type="range"
    classname=beforeSlider ? "sliderWithoutborder" : "sliderWithBorder"
   />
</div>
```

```css
.sliderWithBorder {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 94.5%;
  outline: none;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  border: solid 1px #9b9a9a;
  margin-left: 14px;
}

.sliderWithoutBorder {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 94.5%;
  outline: none;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  margin-left: 14px;
}
```

But what should be written instead of `beforeSlider`?